# Dynamic Sheet Index Number

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a function that returns the index number of the sheet that the function is in.

I have this:

```
Function Sheet()    
Sheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Index    
End Function
```

I have multiple sheets in the workbook which all use the function but all need to refer to their own specific sheets. Using "activesheet" as soon as I update one sheet, all of the other sheets change their results to that new sheet instead of keeping to their own worksheet.

Is there a way to limit the function to the only the worksheet that it is on?

Comment: What do you mean "the sheet the function is in"? Your VBA stuff is saved in the workbook (or even outside), not the sheets. If you mean the sheet the function is called from, then save the value in a (hidden) cell in the sheet?

Answer (score 2):

In Excel 2016, Excel 2013, Excel Online, Excel 2016 for Mac you can use Built-In Excel Function:

```
=SHEET()
```

Otherwise, use chris neilsen method or similar way from: [Get sheet index number from cell reference (Function)](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=402)

```
Function SheetNum(Optional celRef As Range) As Long 

    With Application.Caller.Parent 
        If celRef Is Nothing Then 
            SheetNum = .Index 
        Else 
            SheetNum = celRef.Parent.Index 
        End If 
    End With 

End Function
```

**Suggesting**: change the name of your UDF from `Sheet` to anything like `MySheet`.

if you want a formula to get the name of the worksheet (not the index) you can use this formula:

```
=REPLACE(CELL("filename"),1,FIND("]",CELL("filename")),"")
```

Comment: How would he use `SHEET()` in a UDF?  I do not see that as a member of the WorksheetFunction class.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, SHEET is a Built-In Function in Excel 2016 then we don't need any UDF, just use `=SHEET()`, see: [SHEET function](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/SHEET-function-44718b6f-8b87-47a1-a9d6-b701c06cff24)

Comment: How does that help his problem, which is to figure out which worksheet the UDF is located on?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, from the question and the code we know that he need to return the index of the sheets, and I think the UDF can't return more than one value, if he has a UDF that return other value then he couldn't use it to return the sheet index too.

Comment: I interpreted the question as having his UDF determine the index of the worksheet it was located on.  This can be simply with `Application.Caller.Worksheet.Index` (if the UDF is being called from a worksheet).  I did not see where he wanted the UDF to return the sheet index to the worksheet.  And UDF'

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Application.Caller` to get a reference to the cell the UDF is in. From there is easy to get the index

```
Function Sheet()
    Dim rng as Range
    Set rng = Application.Caller
    Sheet = rng.Worksheet.Index
End Function
```

Please refer to the Help for full details of Caller and add appropriate error handling

Comment: Also - `Application.ThisCell`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use range names (range formula) that utilise Excel's XLM langauage

1. Define a range name, *ShtNames*, as `=GET.WORKBOOK(1+0*RAND())`
2. Define a second range name, *ShtName* as `=GET.CELL(32+0*NOW(),INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(REFTEXT(!$A$1),1,""),FALSE))`

Then in the sheet where you want the Index,
`=MATCH(ShtName,ShtNAmes,0)`

*Updates for Fadi's question*

Rather than add the second name, you could use a formula as below (from any sheet) to return the sheet name to look up against *AllSheets*
So say in `A1` of sheet 1

`=MATCH(RIGHT(CELL("filename",Sheet2!A1),LEN(CELL("filename",Sheet2!A1))-FIND("[",CELL("filename",Sheet2!A1))+1),AllSheets,0)`

would return the sheet position of `Sheet2`

Comment: Thanks @brettdj, I hope that I can upvote this answer more than one time, but I have a question: `=shtNames` formula returns the first sheet name, can we use it to return other sheets names, i tried `=shtNames(2)` and get `#REF!`.

Comment: my (named range) name is `ShtNames` so i replace `AllSheets` with `ShtNames`, and it works perfectly on both Excel 2010 and 2016, thank you again for your help.